# How do I access an external and different document using jquery & js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jsp

I have 3 files. a1.js, a2.js.& main.jsp. Main.jsp has two tabs each having its own functions. a1.js can access 1st tab elements which has multiple checkboxes and a text area where the options selected in the check boxes would be added to the text area. a2.js can access 2nd tab elements which has two radio buttons (yes / no). Depending on the input of the radio buttons, I want some check boxes to checked or unchecked in the 1st tab. How can I acheive this using javascript or jquery? Here is the code:

a1.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Sample Web page</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function changeTA() {
   var inputElements = document.getElementsByName("favorite_pet");
       for(var i=0; inputElements[i]; ++i){
           if(inputElements[i].checked){
               $('#ta').val($('#ta').val()+inputElements[i].value); 
     }
   }
   }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>  
   <legend>What is Your Favorite Pet?</legend>  
   <input type="checkbox" name="favorite_pet" id="check_cat" value="Cats" onchange="changeTA()">Cats<br>  
   <input type="checkbox" name="favorite_pet" id="check_dog" value="Dogs" onchange="changeTA()">Dogs<br>  
   <input type="checkbox" name="favorite_pet" id="check_bird" value="Birds" onchange="changeTA()">Birds<br>  
       <br>  

   <textarea id="ta" rows="4" cols="50">
   </textarea>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

a2.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Sample Web page</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function changeTA() {
    ///code to make changes in a2.jsp
   }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>  
   <legend>Do you want Cat?</legend>  
   <input type="radio" name="CatLover" id="cat_yes" value="yes" onclick="changeTA()">Yes<br>  
   <input type="radio" name="CatLover" id="cat_no" value="no" onclick="changeTA()">No<br>  
   <input type="submit" value="Submit"
       <br> 
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

What I want to when yes is checked in the second jsp page, cats should be added in the text are in the first html and clicking on submit should submit the data from both jsp's/ Also, something t be noted both jsp s are included in another jsp page on different tabs. How can I acheive this?